# brand image skewed and distorted not clipped correctly in android app. It's varying according to the nexus and pixel emulators

Tags: android, user-interface

Android bug-Brand image skewed and distorted not clipped correctly on the splash screen and It's varying according to the nexus and the pixel emulators.

How to solve this issue and what might be the reasons for this issue.

Comment: You should show your code resulting such issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your splash screen Theme in styles.xml you should provide an icon to it:

```
<style name="Theme.AppSplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/app_launcher</item>
        ...
```

Create drawable file, name it "splash_icon.xml" with this content:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="108dp"
        android:height="108dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

and replace `@drawable/app_icon` with your icon. Then use this file in your splash screen theme:

```
<style name="Theme.AppSplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_icon</item>
        ...
```

##### Why 108dp?

Basically according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen) splash screen has own views with concreted sizes. If your icon size bigger than 108dp it will be cut off at the edges cause it placed in circle shaped layout.